# How to add PHP pagination in array's

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I've been trying a lot of ways to add PHP pagination. I have tried searching and trying to figure other ways of implementing the pagination but none of them work.

Here's how I created the Index page:

```
<?php
$menuItems = array(
    "post1" => array(
        "title" => "Sample Title",
        "utime" => "M/d/Y",
        "content" => "<p>Body of the post</p>"
    ),

    "post2" => array(
        "title" => "Another Sample Title",
        "utime" => "M/d/Y",
        "content" => "<p>Content goes here...</p>"
    ),
);

foreach ($menuItems as $contItem => $item) {
?>
<li>
     <a href="dish.php?item=<?php echo $contItem; ?>">
         <h1><?php echo $item["title"]; ?></h1>
         <small><?php echo $item["utime"]; ?></small>
     </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

I would like to know how I can paginate the the array list. Thanks!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

u can use simple PHP function called **array_slice()**

```
$menuItems = array_slice( $menuItems, 0, 10 );
```

show first 10 items.

```
$menuItems = array_slice( $menuItems, 10, 10 );
```

show next 10 items.

**UPDATE:**

```
$page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$total = count( $yourDataArray ); //total items in array    
$limit = 20; //per page    
$totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); //calculate total pages
$page = max($page, 1); //get 1 page when $_GET['page'] <= 0
$page = min($page, $totalPages); //get last page when $_GET['page'] > $totalPages
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;

$yourDataArray = array_slice( $yourDataArray, $offset, $limit );
```

**UPDATE#2:**

Example of pagination:

```
$link = 'index.php?page=%d';
$pagerContainer = '<div style="width: 300px;">';   
if( $totalPages != 0 ) 
{
  if( $page == 1 ) 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= ''; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> &#171; prev page</a>', $page - 1 ); 
  }
  $pagerContainer .= ' <span> page <strong>' . $page . '</strong> from ' . $totalPages . '</span>'; 
  if( $page == $totalPages ) 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= ''; 
  }
  else 
  { 
    $pagerContainer .= sprintf( '<a href="' . $link . '" style="color: #c00"> next page &#187; </a>', $page + 1 ); 
  }           
}                   
$pagerContainer .= '</div>';

echo $pagerContainer;
```

Comment: That does not look Dynamic at all, I mean I will have to manually write the number of the array, Is there any way to have a dynamic pagination that auto counts the array's and does the pagination?

Comment: It shows a couple of error messages like: Notice: Undefined variable: yourDataArray in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\arrayTest\index.php on line 36
-
Notice: Undefined variable: yourDataArray in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\arrayTest\index.php on line 44
-
Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\arrayTest\index.php on line 44

Comment: `$yourDataArray` variable change to `$menuItems` its just a name of array where store items.

Comment: It works but where do I echo the next - 1234.. and prev links and how. Thank You :)

Comment: beacuse I have no idea about these pagination's.

Comment: Please again. Do You need pagination elements likes next page, page X, prev page?

Comment: yes, I do need it but I don't know how and where to put those buttons?

Comment: I can't see the buttons, and it doesn't show any errors?

Comment: `echo $pagerContainer;` put inside your html code, for example after `</ul>` tag. Rest code put after `array_slice()`. I tested this code and i know its works!

Comment: I didn't get it? the example you're showing me is already inside the 2nd Update. Please help!

Comment: Thank you It works just the way I wanted it to, Thank You again!

Comment: Hi, can you show us again the pagination with page numbers on it? I tried clicking on the link you gave http://pastebin.com/Be8HZZKT but it has been removed. Thank you @trzyeM-

Comment: @jhedm ok, but later

Answer (score 21):

Another viable option is to use `array_chunk()`:

```
$pagedArray = array_chunk($originalArray, 10, true);
$nthPage = $pagedArray[$pageNumber];
```