# How to handle pagination in foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the pagination on results from an array. In the array form I want to process the query one by one. In this situation, how do I handle the limit? I need to iterate through the loop and apply the pagination.

For a single query it's ok:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE ORG_NAME_ENGLISH='$search' ORDER BY `Sub-type` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

For records in the array, how to handle pagination?

```
$total_pages=count($oidArr);
$targetpage = "paginate.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 7;                                 //how many items to show per                                 page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this     page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    foreach($oidArr as $orgid)
    {
      echo $start;
      echo $limit;

      /* Get data. */
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `oID`='$orgid' ORDER BY `Sub-type` DESC LIMIT $start,$limit";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: Where does `$oidArr` come from? What's in it?  It looks like each item in it is a page since `$total_pages = count($oidArr)`.  Don't loop through pages, just run the query for what should appear on *this page* and loop through the results.

Comment: $oidArr is Array i just want to know how to get the pagination when the values get in the form of Array because when the loop is iterated a new query runs in each query limit 0,7 remains true

Comment: Of course it is... but what are the contents?  Why are you looping over them?  It seems like you'd just want to do one query and loop over the results instead of a *separate* query for each `$orgid`... unless I'm missing something. Go into detail about what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Thanks Jay
This query is OK because on query getting many records
$sql = "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE ORG_NAME_ENGLISH='$search' ORDER BY `Sub-type` DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

This query have problem its get one record at a time
foreach($oidArr as $orgid)
    {
      echo $start;
      echo $limit;

      /* Get data. */
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `oID`='$orgid' ORDER BY `Sub-type` DESC LIMIT $start,$limit";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
 Here limit 0,7 always remain true at each iteration in this way all records appear on one page

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getDataPerPageByOrgId($orgId, $page, $limit)
{
 // count the all the rows data that meet the requirement   
$total_pages = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from listing WHERE `oID`='$orgId' ");

   // from where should we load data 
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;       

  // Get data. 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `listing` WHERE `oID`='$orgid' ORDER BY `Sub-type` DESC LIMIT $offset ,$limit";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  $data=[$result, $total_pages];
 return $data;
}
```

This method return a multidimensional array containing all data you need for display. `$data[0]` contains your data that you can just loop for a display and `$data[1]` the number of page that you can display as link in the end of your data list as 1-2-**3**-4-5
if you have problem with you data. just try `print_r($data)` to check if your result is really what you are expecting and how to get inside your array.

Answer (score 0):

**array_slice** function is used to paginate through the Array.

[Pagination with Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451362/how-to-add-php-pagination-in-arrays)

[Complete Code](http://snipplr.com/view/9531/array-pagination/)

I think these links are useful to you having this problem