# WordPress create custom pagination in a multiple wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two WP_QUERY in the front-page.php, now in this code I want to insert a pagination to them. So I just want to ask guys if this possible to have it?

**CODE**

```
$events = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'asc'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $events );
$show_events = $the_query->get_posts();

$videos = array(
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'asc'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $videos );
$show_videos = $the_query->get_posts();

$modEvent = count($show_events) / 3;

$eventPerRow = 3;
$eventVidPerRow = 2;

for( $i = 1; $i <= $modEvent; $i++ ) {
    $toStartEvent = ( $i == 1 ) ? 0 : ($i - 1) * $eventPerRow;
    $toStopEvent = ($i * $eventPerRow) -1;
    foreach( $show_events as $key => $event ) :
        //display events data
    endforeach;

    $toStartEventVid = ( $i == 1 ) ? 0 : ($i - 1) * $eventVidPerRow;
    $toStopEventVid = ($i * $eventVidPerRow) -1;
    foreach( $show_videos as $key => $videos ) :
        //display videos data
    endforeach;

    //PAGINATION HERE
}
```

Comment: please post your code as text in your message and not as an image

Comment: http://wordpress-ajax-pagination.com/multiple-posts-set-up check this example

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ please check again thanks :)

Comment: @ShivangiVyas thanks for answering, but i need is for a multiple wp_query :(

Comment: From what i remember you can get multiple post-types with one query ```'post_type' => array('events', 'videos')```. Then you could use the wordpress pagination as described here https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: @sbrn yep ! actually its working, but in this code 'post_type' => array('events', 'videos') what happened was it won't get my goal in front end the 3 column for events, and 2 column for video and its getting random ...  please check the site >> http://demo.sytian-productions.com/nb/.

what i want is in a 10 post per page, it will show be 3 column for events, 2 column for videos repeatedly.

Comment: Maybe the plugin advanced-custom-fields is helpful?
 https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/. I can't think of a way to solve this by just using one wp query. Even with two, it gets tricky but u can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451362/how-to-add-php-pagination-in-arrays array pagination. But then you would have to build the array manually.